# SSIS Error Output to Eventhandler and to Flat File

Tags: error-handling, ssis, sql-server-2012

In an SSIS Data Flow Task (SSDT 2012) I would like to route a Lookup Error Output to a Flat File Destination and simultaneously I would like to activate the OnError event handler to execute a Script Component to do other things.

Is it possible to route an error to a Flat File and to an event handler?

Comment: Help me understand what problem you're solving. A lookup doesn't find a match. You want to log it to a file for investigation, which allows the data flow to continue executing. *But*, you'd also like the OnError event to fire which will stop the Data Flow's execution.

Comment: Are you facing any issues while trying to dump the data to Flat File from Lookup No Match Output? If so, whats the issue? You cannot invoke OnError unless there is an error within the package. What you could do is write a script within onPostExecute for the container housing the lookup. Makes sense?

Comment: To billinkc: Yes, you are right: I would like to have both: A Flat File AND additionally an OnError Event!

Comment: To rvphx: Yes, using a script makes sense! Thanks so far. Concerning your issue question: I mean that routing the not matching data to the Lookup Error Output would create an issue/error so that this would invoke OnError!??